# improving for...in loop to be faster in Typescript

Tags: typescript, for-loop, asynchronous

so I've been asked to improve a code that uses "for...in" of typescript to be faster.

this is the original code:

```
    export interface AddressBook {
    emp_id: string | null;
    first: string;
    last: string;
    email: string;
}
export interface Payroll {
    emp_id: string;
    vacationDays: number;
}
interface Employee {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date | null;
}
export interface EmailApi {
    sendEmail(email: string, subject: string, body: string): void;
}
function yearsSince(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): number {
    const millisecondsPerYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return Math.trunc((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / millisecondsPerYear);
}
/**
 * We haved decided to grant bonus vacation to every employee, 1 day per year of experience
 * we need to email them a notice.
 */

function grantVacation(
    emailApi: EmailApi,
    payroll: Payroll[],
    addresses: AddressBook[],
    employees: Employee[],
) {
    for (var index in payroll) {
        let payrollInfo = payroll[index];
        let addressInfo = addresses.find(x => x.emp_id == payrollInfo.emp_id);
        let empInfo = employees.find(x => x.id == payrollInfo.emp_id);
        let today = new Date();
        let yearsEmployed = 0;
        if (empInfo != undefined) {
            yearsEmployed = yearsSince(empInfo.startDate, today);
        }
        let newVacationBalance = yearsEmployed + payrollInfo.vacationDays;
        if (addressInfo != undefined && empInfo != undefined) {
            emailApi.sendEmail(
                addressInfo.email,
                "Good news!",
                `Dear ${empInfo.name}\n` +
                `based on your ${yearsEmployed} years of employment, you have been granted ${yearsEmployed} days of vacation, bringing your total to ${newVacationBalance}`
            );
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd();
}

// for the testing part I'll implement sendEmail as printing:
class myEmailApi implements EmailApi {
    sendEmail(email: string, subject: string, body: string): void {
        console.log('********************');
        console.log(`To ${email}, Subject: ${subject}, body: ${body}`);
        console.log('********************');
    }
}

let myPayroll: Payroll[] = [
    { emp_id: "1", vacationDays: 1 },
    { emp_id: "2", vacationDays: 2 },
    { emp_id: "3", vacationDays: 3 },
    { emp_id: "4", vacationDays: 4 },
    { emp_id: "5", vacationDays: 5 },
    { emp_id: "6", vacationDays: 6 }
];

let myAdress: AddressBook[] = [
    { emp_id: "1", first: "emp", last: "number 1", email: "emp1@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "2", first: "emp", last: "number 2", email: "emp2@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "3", first: "emp", last: "number 3", email: "emp3@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "4", first: "emp", last: "number 4", email: "emp4@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "5", first: "emp", last: "number 5", email: "emp5@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "6", first: "emp", last: "number 6", email: "emp6@gmail.com" },
];

let myEmployees: Employee[] = [
    { id: "1", name: "emp number 1", startDate: new Date("2020-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "2", name: "emp number 2", startDate: new Date("2019-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "3", name: "emp number 3", startDate: new Date("2018-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "4", name: "emp number 4", startDate: new Date("2017-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "5", name: "emp number 5", startDate: new Date("2016-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "6", name: "emp number 6", startDate: new Date("2015-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
];

grantVacation(new myEmailApi(), myPayroll, myAdress, myEmployees);
```

There is nothing special here, this is a demo for sending email to every employee in the company after calculating the new vacation days of the employees.

So I've already read that using "for...in" is really slow in comperance to the other loops (while, for, foreach) and should not be used since it uses a lookup mechnism for every property which makes the code really slow.

I tried to improve the code like this (using async) but when I measured the time I found out both version are somewhat the same, or even worse for the improvment which means my solution at least didn't improve the performance

the improved version of my code is:

```
export interface AddressBook {
    emp_id: string | null;
    first: string;
    last: string;
    email: string;
}
export interface Payroll {
    emp_id: string;
    vacationDays: number;
}
interface Employee {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date | null;
}
export interface EmailApi {
    sendEmail(email: string, subject: string, body: string): void;
}
function yearsSince(startDate: Date, endDate: Date): number {
    const millisecondsPerYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return Math.trunc((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / millisecondsPerYear);
}
/**
 * We haved decided to grant bonus vacation to every employee, 1 day per year of experience
 * we need to email them a notice.
 */

function calculateVacation(payrollInfo: Payroll, empInfo: Employee): Promise<any> {
    // "wrap" a sync function inside of a promise and finish the calulation.
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let today = new Date();
        let yearsEmployed = 0;

        if (empInfo != undefined) {
            yearsEmployed = yearsSince(empInfo.startDate, today);
        }
        let newVacationBalance = yearsEmployed + payrollInfo.vacationDays;
        // return all the relevant values from this promise as a single array to use.
        resolve([empInfo?.name, yearsEmployed, newVacationBalance]);
    });
}

async function asyncSendEmail(emailApi: EmailApi, payrollInfo: Payroll, addresses: AddressBook[], employees: Employee[]) {
    //Moran's note: adding a timer to see the performance.
    const startTime = Date.now();
    let addressInfo = addresses.find(x => x.emp_id == payrollInfo.emp_id);
    await Promise.all(employees.map(empInfo => {
        if (empInfo.id == payrollInfo.emp_id) {
            calculateVacation(payrollInfo, empInfo)
                .then(([empInfoName, yearsEmployed, newVacationBalance]) => {
                    if (addressInfo != undefined) {
                        emailApi.sendEmail(
                            addressInfo.email,
                            "Good news!",
                            `Dear ${empInfoName}\n` +
                            `based on your ${yearsEmployed} years of employment, you have been granted ${yearsEmployed} days of vacation, bringing your total to ${newVacationBalance}`
                        );
                    }
                });
        }
    }));
    const msElapsed = Date.now() - startTime;
    console.log(`Async function took ${msElapsed} ms to complete.`);
}

function grantVacation(
    emailApi: EmailApi,
    payroll: Payroll[],
    addresses: AddressBook[],
    employees: Employee[]) {

    for (let i = 0; i < payroll.length; i++) {
        let payrollInfo = payroll[i];
        asyncSendEmail(emailApi, payrollInfo, addresses, employees);
    }
}

// for the testing part I'll implement sendEmail as printing:
class myEmailApi implements EmailApi {
    sendEmail(email: string, subject: string, body: string): void {
        console.log('********************');
        console.log(`To ${email}, Subject: ${subject}, body: ${body}`);
        console.log('********************');
    }
}

let myPayroll: Payroll[] = [
    { emp_id: "1", vacationDays: 1 },
    { emp_id: "2", vacationDays: 2 },
    { emp_id: "3", vacationDays: 3 },
    { emp_id: "4", vacationDays: 4 },
    { emp_id: "5", vacationDays: 5 },
    { emp_id: "6", vacationDays: 6 }
];

let myAdress: AddressBook[] = [
    { emp_id: "1", first: "emp", last: "number 1", email: "emp1@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "2", first: "emp", last: "number 2", email: "emp2@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "3", first: "emp", last: "number 3", email: "emp3@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "4", first: "emp", last: "number 4", email: "emp4@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "5", first: "emp", last: "number 5", email: "emp5@gmail.com" },
    { emp_id: "6", first: "emp", last: "number 6", email: "emp6@gmail.com" },
];

let myEmployees: Employee[] = [
    { id: "1", name: "emp number 1", startDate: new Date("2020-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "2", name: "emp number 2", startDate: new Date("2019-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "3", name: "emp number 3", startDate: new Date("2018-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "4", name: "emp number 4", startDate: new Date("2017-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "5", name: "emp number 5", startDate: new Date("2016-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
    { id: "6", name: "emp number 6", startDate: new Date("2015-01-01"), endDate: new Date("2025-01-01") },
];

grantVacation(new myEmailApi(), myPayroll, myAdress, myEmployees);
```

I would really like to know what did I do wrong? maybe my way of implementing it as async missed some basic knowledge?
maybe the code is okay but when measuring the time for the given tested data (I could make it even greater then 6) is just too small?

thanks in advance

Comment: `calculateVacation` doesn’t seem to invoke any asynchronous calls, so there’s no performance benefits from wrapping synchronous code in a Promise. See https://fagnerbrack.medium.com/promises-sync-code-disaster-e9d41a3c7279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to improve (see [updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwDwBUB8UC8UBKEAxgPYBOCqAzsGQJZwDmANFFgNwBQnDwEZAMwCGRaAEEECMhCpUAQiRIBrKAG9OUTVAgBbMAH06CAFxQa9Jly1QBdMjVPmGjK1oA2Qh2drPXm3UJ0bo4+lpwAvhq8-MKiUAAKQiBkJG5uahpaugZGIRYumZoAbiJCwHQkcAAiSVSmcACuOgBG-FyR0YIi0ACiem4kIBDQ6ta53vl+UHBCOhB5voXeQmTANXym6xBTEIhbm2XQAD7TDWntPHB8XXF9gW5iYHQZ1lS7CHdBABQBQQtMrCoDWaACtiMB-iwoM0SAgQJCAJSmIokIwXAQNOBEcqVKBDFZUADKDFEXxoKzWhwOfFY732UC2SNOLX4Ly0pDgNCgOiCbjobw5CCo8X4AE0ICtcFAAMwANgArFAAFRQABMABZlVBZQAGLW6rUARh1Jqm0mADTIcCgAFkygALAB0tExRC+Pz2h0djAgwHQdDmXwRUAAtMtVltvb7-YGEcGAPTc3n84iVIUisjilYIi7xpVKjQqgDq0HtQiKEAQUCQRCMlagwBIUEYZCEV2hlQaVCgJSIZQq1sb2grZBA2n6g2GrEN1aSUEgZDxEsXJAE2mQC7ou1EhagAHdoHBhlWh790sB7booEJpiRyqJHYX49wMVicda+24iGdDgA1Urvl8YBJCkaTwAIJCmIkySpG4tJ6OBkFQH0YADEMEDBqM7KVFyjYIHOeBHnuDKHEGUwcly+L2ChaH1ng2SIbgOB4JiSC2EeVYAPxQHqphUUSJIQD8CFwBBjrkhGhysHhSQ5ksFHANMEB7v+fbvnIQgeFi0B4PxNGTlWADU84gbBiGOr2-aVDUIBUFM8aJualrWpp56XlA0huBAJTtiUbgNDINgpDoDb2vy87BSm17djeVDOF515kK2Y5Dl2ECPtYTlWlAADaDGiSQjozHMrB6ROQwIKwRGqVZcAaVpogALoXJwr7YgOZjvJ8bhfJkZ6PHQpjdQNzCZMBMFgQVUGmWko2aEIkjSLIMimPASBoBIUgyPIihKJgc3jqhk4rbAiAoKg+noZgnCYfJOGKRJfoBjpJF8EVJB7mRd2copC1bbIjF4H9S1vFQOXjaBbjmdkhgIM1Sx0GuXzA9tgPMVArEQOxla3dYmhZXAUyRN9XJ5SJEEAHKzBApXLlQl2VlVyk1epmltk1Uqft+Hh8CzA5ATNUMFfBR3oWDENmQVjow0YjVydY-VPOJXU6PcvV49ei2o1LZ4HdYABEADiihVkRVAAIT63rWgAAZVMuUAACSqPllPU+EAA6cA21AhlLJoNvNJ49a4iAJCWk7qhlaLlbhEuBJQKuh1oXMVyleHUBlhW0LDNaLZtnwVbO9HtEIHH+G2Yna6We+rDNPkzh4uHi6NsAmkNk2zvVQBA71ezEDhDbSzy1oJOKTo9MeGAbxVngkZwB9QahuGT1zOROGpOlAyMF8Ntte+HfKJHE89FPM9xxPHdQKQ-S+ulNtycT+8dfnVx85U6tZKrQQDUN38PE8a2Es0jTQmm4HKjVrYo2WnUU661UCbRBgoZQ+0ljZFoidNa50GYQEwLdJYwC3COggmQHoIh7QCzAYDbAWENZvEQN1YS9wRomSocLTW-1QYiwwVQEemhwiP24A5Gw5BQrQD4DQRuwFViwAAORpCgAGVCuhdgPRVvcaKEVeDOGMJwIgHhZDchAMNJ4ijb6p2AN2ExzxaGdQYf-JhfwJjOEBMCME2JIR11hPCZxTAmQoiMGyDWFFN6Om3l8WR+YonRJibE2RfC8YhK8mEkgO8bboE7i7f+4RWCEjceCUwzsgSgnBDkjscJCmqBhHCQeCTrBJK3qkiJsSWktPiUTCI3AvLjxANBSGoDIYQKlDlJYqhDqw1MPrQ0Vsew92srUUwM4cmjPGeMfWqoZk1wHDZWBqooDLOsGMmWJgoD62lJsuZ1QFkyn2dbI5egJmnPVBctS2zrmagOVoe5OQTn63lC82qOzTCKk+Zob5jz9aygBe+IF2p9mcHhpwbpRiJAg1MIg7ayClBDLwCMw5qzfnTNYLYewEJTnZBmQYsl+tGgskXES8c9xJnZENAAAUYP-R0N99a3JWccyZGziV2C8PrClrAqWTNpa0RcgrGVONFXoVU7LOXct5fi-lpzzlCtJcyvQlLPDUqlayLVcrgjkr0NKZV9wuUkB0Dy0FagCWTOedqkVYqoAStOUaxcLrTW6rAOqK1QQbV2rVV8p1pz-muupe6z1NKmjSqgFGv15qwDyiDUQ1VDrwVrKhdG-1+qRXeu1DMs8-rZQZpDfa0aiLkU6GMeVYYsCcE4tyistZDLirzFTcyRNDLHr0iIq9IS6ydSqh1CGHUhpJ3TIRLST0GwlLES2F8Udqp5QzpnfrYM2bFG-NlV2-1vbWSyoHVSJdw7V3jsNAATk3VO7d86ECDuUpetdG6p1bp3XcvdkyTWHp7cWk1Z7F1DpXaOw0AAOe9s6n0vuXaRd9MHt1hrBb+p5MyAMKrAMen1MyQPdrA4h69AB2ZDc7tALsI6+8D4713kdQ46tZyasPZFw0m-DbdJKgZo8RqdspyNwfPURvgV6x0funQ+797bfl5umNTI9xa5MEfqLx0TEGJNfqEzxhD6m6Oaak7yxFCkOFIIbWAGAs8oAAHkSnYmIcFHoVx6AyC+PW1F21HSqzAO6HNlUoCOkC0tRSAjcDYDJj81gfnWCBcdMF-Zcs5ImfQcdeQIBLNSls+44ADnbVOZ8K5+tOCqBeaED5r4YyjAxaCzIELwYcDhaq0x-zsX4vhES1wTgr9gDvzgF8IdRX-4DSDKwetfTYKsGgWllClnuGpbkOlhAckgA))

1. `calculateVacation` doesn’t seem to invoke any asynchronous calls, so there’s [no performance benefits](https://fagnerbrack.medium.com/promises-sync-code-disaster-e9d41a3c7279) from wrapping synchronous code in a Promise.
2. Index your address book and employee lists by employee ID for constant time lookups. I.e. convert the list of entries into a record that maps employee IDs to the entry.
3. Rearrange your logic in `(async)sendEmail` - if addressInfo is undefined, return from the function; calling `calculateVacation` is redundant in this case.

`sendEmail` function took 37-49 ms in your OP; now it goes down to 11-13ms per invocation.

Comment: Hi anson I need to read more about the solution since i'm not familiar with the index operation that you used.

I do understand now that the sync with async is less desirable and less working anyway so thanks for that Anson - very intersting solution that i'm not familiar with.

any other catches do you think for even more improvment or this is the final result?

Comment: The "index" is just an object that maps employee IDs to your existing object. E.g. an index for address book will map employee IDs to their corresponding address. As far as optimisations go, that's it from me.

Comment: got it... I also see that you are using es2019 with the fromEnteries which i'm not familiar with this syntex so I'll read about that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use for-of
2. The slowest part, looking at the code, seems to be the 2 "find"s
3. You'll need a way higher amount of entries to notice actual improvements

If speed is what you're looking for, in this case you might want to create maps from addresses and employees; this way you'll have to entirely transverse addresses and employees only once each.

Here's an example:

```js
const addressesMap: Record<string, AddressBook> = addresses.reduce((obj, address) => ({[address.emp_id!]: address, ...obj}), {}); // NOTE: just for the example, considered emp_id as never null; consider removing null on the type declaration OR add a check here when creating the map
const employeesMap: Record<string, Employee> = employees.reduce((obj, employee) => ({[employee.id]: employee, ...obj}), {});

for (let payrollInfo of payroll) {
    let addressInfo = addressesMap[payrollInfo.emp_id];
    let empInfo = employeesMap[payrollInfo.emp_id];
    let today = new Date();
    let yearsEmployed = 0;
    if (empInfo != undefined) {
        yearsEmployed = yearsSince(empInfo.startDate, today);
    }
    let newVacationBalance = yearsEmployed + payrollInfo.vacationDays;
    if (addressInfo != undefined && empInfo != undefined) {
        emailApi.sendEmail(
            addressInfo.email,
            "Good news!",
            `Dear ${empInfo.name}\n` +
            `based on your ${yearsEmployed} years of employment, you have been granted ${yearsEmployed} days of vacation, bringing your total to ${newVacationBalance}`
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: hi first of all thanks I'll try to play with this solution a bit more to uderstand the reduce part.
what is the difference betweeb "for... of" and "for...in" btw?

so the async operation wasn't the catch of the improvment only the finding part?

thatnks Giovanni

Comment: for-of iterates through the array normally, while the for-in iterates over all the object's enumerable properties (you can read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). That's not the real slow part anyway. --
There's wasn't a need for async operation, there's nothing slow there, and you might expect a sendEmail to be async already in a real situation anyway. -- The reduce part just creates a map (an "object" in js) so it requires constant time to access any entry instead of transversing the array as "find" would do.

Comment: The answer you accepted does exactly the same thing, it just calls it index/record.

Comment: cool got it will read everything you both guys did and make sure I understand everything thanks guys you both rock :)

Comment: btw the code itself that you mentioned isn't working as is

1. [address.emp_id] raised error of: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

2. when calling the maps, also raised error of:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

so I do understand the code but those are compilation errors in your codr :)

Comment: @moranabilea it depends on the TS settings, it worked on my machine but I confirm it's not working in the TS playground, so it might be my configuration; still it doesn't change the algorithm. Number 1 error is caused by the `interface AddressBook { emp_id: string | null; ... }` (the "null"), which I kept; you can consider removing the `| null` as in the accepted answer, or add a check in the creation of the map. Number 2 can be resolved adding the type declaration (`const addressesMap: Record<string, AddressBook> = ...` and `const employeesMap: Record<string, Employee> =` for example)

Comment: @moranabilea updated the code to make it work in the playground, but the take home message is still "create an object (map, index, call it as you want) to have constant time lookups and avoid transversing the arrays on every iteration"

Comment: thanks! I get it now... yeah the algorithm needs to stay the same I just tried to fix the compilations error and I did it wrong so now it is working.

well I can't get rid of the " | null" part since it is required but the null check is fine or using the bang operator... 

I used a regular VScode files so I guess you are right the settings can be different sometimes but I got the main idea - using mapping/indexing so I won't need to lookup in the array in O(N) times instead just use it in O(1).